# Change color of menu bar in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, color-scheme

I want to change the color of the menu bar of PyCharm.

I found a lot of color settings, but up to now I could not find what I am looking for.

Background: I have several instances running at once, and I want to see/feel the difference at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> Appearance -> Theme